# form aligned to right

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, jsp, alignment

My question is I use the code below for a registration form. It work ok in Firefox and Google Chrome. But this entire page is aligned to left in when I use Internet Explorer. I have checked the CSS, but there is no porblem with it. Please help me to solve this:

```
<!-- checking the session -->
    <% 
    try{    
    %>
    <%@ include file="checksession.jsp"%>
    <%
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    %>
    <jsp:forward page="session.jsp" />
    <%
    }
    %>

    <%@page import="cls.dateconverter"%>
    <%@include file="includePade/connection.jsp"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="css_inside/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css_inside/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/marquee.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="script/ajax_admin.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <!---------(For Combo Box)---end------->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="top-band">
      <div class="signinband" style="width: 100%">
      <div class="sms">
      </div><!--sms-->
        <div class="sign-in-box" Style="width:600px;text-align: right;" ><p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li style="border:none;"><a href="logout.jsp">Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>
        </div><!--sign-in-box-->
      </div><!--signinband-->
    </div><!--top-band-->
    <div class="container_12 wrapper" style="margin: auto;">
    <div class="grid_12 inner">
    <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="grid_12 inner">
        <div class="grid_12 footer-info alpha">
    <p>This is city based free classified website that help people buy,sell,rent,lease. You can post free ads and reply to ads on web or direct in the city you live in.</p></div><!--footer-info-->
        <div class="grid_12 futer alpha">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="slash">|</li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li class="slash">|</li>

          <li><a href="#">privacy policy</a></li>
          <li class="slash">|</li>
          <li><a href="#">Term of Use</a></li>
          <li class="slash">|</li>
          <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
          <li class="slash">|</li>

          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--futer-->
        <div class="grid_12 futer alpha" style="text-align:center">
       Copyright &#169; 2012 <a href="index.jsp">myclient.com </a>. All rights reserved  
         </div><!--futer-->
      </div><!--inner-->
      </div>
    </div><!--wrapper-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: where is style.css and the form?

Comment: I have checked the style.css. Its a long css. Thats why I dont post it.

Comment: I dont think you have posted the complete code. Do it if you want any help from here. Try remove each div and check it, If you want to inspect the div use "firebug for IE" or "Microsoft Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar" ( http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite, or http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try remove that comment in the first line "checking the session". Once I had this same problem in IE7. Hope it will solve this. Am not sure in your case, try to post full code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If worked fine when i removed the comment

Comment: you are welcome. From next time please be specific about the questions.